# How to extract month-year from date from MDX Query

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx

I need to filter data from Cube using Date without day inclusion.
Currently I am using following MDX query, that is fetching measures data starting from 1st day of the year and ending on the last day.

But, I only want to have Month-Year in date time at rows rather than DateTime with all days. ( Here my field for date is : [Period].[TransportDate] )

Following is the MDX Query.

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    { 
      [Measures].[ConsignmentCount]
    , [Measures].[CBM]
    , [Measures].[LDM]
    , [Measures].[Weight]
    , [Measures].[Amount] } ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY 
    { [Period].[TransportDate].Children } ON ROWS
FROM 
  ( 
     SELECT 
      ( 
        { [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2014]
        , [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2015] } 
      ) ON COLUMNS
      FROM [RebellOlap]
   )
```

Above query fetching all records starting from 1st day till the last day of 2015. See attached image ( allRecords )

[image]

But I want somehow in following manner ( Required Data Set )
I want single column instead of Month and year. So 
final data set should be

( e.g Date ( 07-2015 ), Amount,CBM, LDM, Num,. Consignments )

[image]

I know there's a way to extract only month and year from the whole date. But that works only for single date. What I want to have all dates must be filtered with the inclusion of month and Year and data should also corresponds to those dates accordingly. See above expected filtered data set.

**Edit**

```
WITH MEMBER [YearMo] AS 
     [Period].[ConsignmentYear].Currentmember.Name 
     + "-" + 
     [Period].[ConsignmentMonth].Currentmember.Name
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    { 
      [Measures].[ConsignmentCount]
    , [Measures].[CBM]
    , [Measures].[LDM]
    , [Measures].[Weight]
    , [Measures].[Amount] 
   } ON COLUMNS , 
NON EMPTY 
   (
     {  
       [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentMonth] 
     } 
   ) ON ROWS 
FROM 
  ( 
     SELECT 
        ( 
          { 
            [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2014]
          , [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2015] 
          } 
        ) ON COLUMNS
     FROM [RebellOlap]
  )
```

above produces result but without Year.

[image]

I want somehow to have year with month on the same columns.
so 01 would becomd 01-2014.
Could you help me

**Results without concatenation**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did my answer help at all, or can I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try hosting the calculated member in a different hierarchy. I have guessed this `[Forwarder].[Forwarder].[All]` and you will need to adjust to a hierarchy that exists in your cube:

```
WITH MEMBER [Forwarder].[Forwarder].[All].[YearMo] AS 
     [Period].[Year].Currentmember.Name 
     + "-" + 
     [Period].[Month].Currentmember.Name
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    { 
      [Measures].[ConsignmentCount]
    , [Measures].[CBM]
    , [Measures].[LDM]
    , [Measures].[Weight]
    , [Measures].[Amount] 
   } ON COLUMNS , 
NON EMPTY 
      [Period].[Year].[Year]
     *[Period].[Month].[Month]
     *[Forwarder].[Forwarder].[All].[YearMo] 
     ON ROWS 
FROM 
  ( 
     SELECT 
        ( 
          { 
            [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2014]
          , [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2015] 
          } 
        ) ON COLUMNS
     FROM [RebellOlap]
  )
```

Or if the above produces an error then you may need to create a measure first:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[YearMoString] AS 
     [Period].[Year].Currentmember.Name 
     + "-" + 
     [Period].[Month].Currentmember.Name
MEMBER [Forwarder].[Forwarder].[All].[YearMo] AS 
     (
       [Forwarder].[Forwarder].[All]
      ,[Measures].[YearMoString]
     )
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    { 
      [Measures].[ConsignmentCount]
    , [Measures].[CBM]
    , [Measures].[LDM]
    , [Measures].[Weight]
    , [Measures].[Amount] 
   } ON COLUMNS , 
NON EMPTY 
      [Period].[Year].[Year]
     *[Period].[Month].[Month]
     *[Forwarder].[Forwarder].[All].[YearMo] 
     ON ROWS 
FROM 
  ( 
     SELECT 
        ( 
          { 
            [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2014]
          , [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2015] 
          } 
        ) ON COLUMNS
     FROM [RebellOlap]
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to create a new field as 'YYYY-mm' in the dimension view (cube design-sql view) or you can concatenate the year & month dimension attributes (Example below).

Example Code:

```
WITH MEMBER [YearMo] AS 
   [Period].[Monthly].Currentmember.Name 
    + "-" + [Period].[YearAndMonth].Currentmember.Name 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY {[Measures].[ConsignmentCount], [Measures].[CBM], [Measures].[LDM], [Measures].[Weight], [Measures].[Amount]} ON COLUMNS 
, NON EMPTY ( { [Period].[Monthly].[Year] } , { [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentMonth] } ) ON ROWS 
FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT ( { [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2014], [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2015] } ) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [RebellOlap]
   )
```

Comment: Hi Usman, Modified your code above. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Hi Hari :
I don't have any hierarchy [Period].[Monthly].

My hierarchies are : [Period].[YearAndHalf], [Period].[YearAndMonth], [Period].[YearAndQuarter] and [Period].[YearAndWeek]

Comment: I think , somehow we are not using concatenation correctly.
On rows we need concatenation like 

('YYYY-MM') => 2014-04 so I don't think so, { [Period].[Monthly].[Year] } , { [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentMonth] } won't work. Because It's not concatenation. Moreover, I don't have any [Period].[Monthly] hierarchy at all.

Comment: Dear Hari, Now I got almost correct results, seems I am very near to goal.
All I need here is concatenation to have single field instead of different sets.
So instead of 2014|1 I need it (2014-01).

So we need concatenation at row level
See edit for having final results after using your suggetion of [Period].[YearAndQuarter].

Comment: Then try the below code, 

WITH MEMBER [YearMo] AS [Period].[YearAndQuarter].Currentmember.Name + "-" + [Period].[YearAndMonth].Currentmember.Name

SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[ConsignmentCount], [Measures].[CBM], [Measures].[LDM], [Measures].[Weight], [Measures].[Amount]} ON COLUMNS , NON EMPTY ( { [Period].[YearAndQuarter].[ConsignmentYear] } , { [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentMonth] } ) ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2014], [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentYear].&[2015] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [RebellOlap])

Comment: see edits Expected Results in red colour inside image

Comment: We almost there, just add the " [YearMo]" in select clause on columns axis
"SELECT NON EMPTY { [YearMo], [Measures].[ConsignmentCount]......."
which I've missed above.

Comment: No no..
then this would become data .
This always have to be on row side.
Because the whole row data corresponds to certain date.
and adding into Column axis resulting #Error. 
Date HAS to have on row side instead of column.

see attached image.

Comment: and putting [YearMo] on Row axis, resulting following error 

'The Measures hierarchy already appears in the Axis0 axis.'

Comment: Then you have to add a new field in the corresponding dimensional SQL view.

Comment: Hari : Thanks for your help and time..
I would certainly do something for adding new field in the cube regarding what we discussed.