# How to convert set to single value for rows in MDX Query?

Tags: reporting-services, filter, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I have following query that is producing the output as shown in the picture.

```
WITH 
SET ConsignmentYear as 
    (
      [Period].[YearAndMonth].[ConsignmentMonth].ALLMEMBERS 
     *[Period].[YearAndQuarter[ConsignmentYear].ALLMEMBERS 
    )
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
   { 
     [Measures].[Amount] 
   , [Measures].[LDM]
   , [Measures].[Weight]
   , [Measures].[CBM] 
   } ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY 
   { (ConsignmentYear) }ON ROWS 
 FROM [RebellOlap]
```

[image]

While I need sets on Row dimension as date ( e.g 1-2014, 2-2014, 3-2014, 12-2014) instead of having a set containing two values separately.

Because, each row corresponds to a date
So I need finally

```
Year        Amount    LDM      Weight       CBM

1-2014----> 2.64       0        191.4        0
2-2014----> 2.64       0        191.4        0
4-2014----> 2.64       0        191.4        0
1-2015----> 2.64       0        191.4        0
...........................................
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: didn't any of this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649145/how-to-extract-month-year-from-date-from-mdx-query

Answer (score 0):

I would use a measure:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[concatenated] AS
      [Date].[Month of Year].CurrentMember.Member_Caption + ' - '
    + 
      [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[concatenated]} ON 0
 ,
    [Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year]*
    [Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Result of above:

[image]

Or change your date dimension so that the concatenated date is a hierarchy of its own within the date dimension